# What is the equivalent of sprintf in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Prolog has an equivalent of the C library printf, which is format/2 or format/3.

But what is the equivalent of sprintf ?

Comment: What's wrong with using `format/3` for that purpose? I mean, ALS Prolog [sprintf/3](https://alsprolog.com/docs/ref/sprintf.html) seems to follow the same approach.

Comment: Some systems provide the non-terminal `format_//2` for that purpose. So use it like `?- phrase(format_("Hello ~s",["World!"]), Xs).`

Comment: @raina77ow I did not express myself correctly. My problem was not that I wanted to use the printf-like format instead of the prolog-like format, it's that I wanted the output to be a variable, as opposed to standard output. I did not understand that format/3 was for this purpose. I confused in my head format/3 and format/2 in which the 2nd argument is a list, when writing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format/3` providing `string(S)` or `atom(A)` as the first argument:

```
?- format(string(String), 'Hello ~w', ['World!']).
String = "Hello World!".

?- format(atom(String), 'Hello ~w', ['World!']).
String = 'Hello World!'.
```